# Is it possible to price a call option given a daily underlying returns distribution?

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes

Apologies in advance if this problem is somewhat ill-posed. But I was thinking given the price of a call option can be formulated in terms of a implied probability density function at time $T$, would it be possible to price a call option given a non-lognormal distribution of *daily* returns?

My question would be how would one scale a daily returns distribution (one that is *not* lognormal) to match the tenor of the option to get the implied distribution of spot at $T$? I would imagine once we have that we can simply compute the below integral to get the price of the option?

$$
c = e^{-rT}*\int_{K}^{\infty}(S-K)p(S)dS
$$

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! You're on the right track. Option pricing can be understood in terms of an integral over the risk-neutral probability distribution of the underlying asset's payoff at expiration. When the distribution of returns is log-normal (as in the Black-Scholes model), the integral simplifies to the familiar Black-Scholes formula. However, if we know the distribution, we can always price the option using the general formula.